# Building GUI Using CSS that runs Python

Tags: html, css

I have started building GUI based App on Python Using TKinter, but Tkinter is less flexile(at least for me) to make a good design ,So i decided to switch to Web App (that runs on local Host) and heard that CSS is good for Designing.So my question Is
Is there a way to run the python code that i have previously written, In the web App that is Designed Using CSS.

Eg:
In my python project with tkinter, a button click would send a notification Using Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Mobile App,I want to implement the same using the Web App.

Comment: `PyQt` using something similar: QSS

Comment: You may be interested in Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/